# Compare two excel files and return non common rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list

I have two excel files like below- 
File1.xlsx
[image: file1]
File2.xlsx
[image: file2]

I want to compare each row and each column and eliminate common rows from both files (except the column heading). The output should look like below -
File1.xlsx
[image: file3]
File2.xlsx
[image: file4]

My code-

```
import pandas
from datetime import datetime
import numpy


df = pandas.read_excel('File1.xlsx')
FORMAT = ['col1','col2','col3']
df_selected = df[FORMAT]

df2 = pandas.read_excel('File2.xlsx')
FORMAT2 = ['col1','col2','col3']
df_selected2 = df2[FORMAT2]



def compare(row1,row2):
    # print(row1,row2)
    flag = False
    i = 0
    for t1, t2 in zip(row1, row2):

        #if it is first value
        #check dates

        if(i==0):
            formattedDT = datetime.strptime(t1, '%d-%b-%Y')

            if(formattedDT!=t2):
                flag = True
                break
        elif(t1!=t2):
            flag = True
            break

        i=i+1

    if(flag is False):
        return 'matched'
    else:
        return 'mismatched'    


def iterate(array1, array2):
    result = array1
    for index, row1 in enumerate(array1):
        for row2 in array2:
            if(compare(row1,row2)=='matched'):
                del result[index]
                break
    df = pandas.DataFrame(result)
    df.columns=['col1','col2','col3']
    writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome', index=False)
    writer.save()    
                



iterate(df_selected.values,df_selected2.values)
```

But I am getting this error output-
ValueError: cannot delete array elements

Please help.

Comment: i think pandas.merge will be helpful here and then look for _merge field. `import pandas as pd
left = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
right = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [7, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
merge=pd.merge(left,right,how="outer",on=['A','B'],indicator=True) `

Comment: @simpleApp can you indent your code and explain your solution. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are all set. Pls let me know if you need any additional support. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution .It should give you desired result

```
df1 =pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx',parse_dates=['col1'],sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_excel('File2.xlsx',parse_dates=['col1'],sep='\t',dayfirst=True)
temp_df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
temp_df.drop_duplicates(subset=['col1','col2','col3'], keep=False, inplace=True)

final_df1 = pd.merge(df1, temp_df, how='inner', on=['col1','col2','col3'])
final_df2 = pd.merge(df2, temp_df, how='inner', on=['col1','col2','col3'])

final_df1.to_excel('file_1_modified.xlsx',index=False)
final_df2.to_excel('file_2_modified.xlsx',index=False)
```

Below are snapshot for my result.Please note I have read from csv files ..so I have used pd.read_csv() on my snapshot. But it will give same result
[image: First Image]
[image: second Image]
[image: Third Image]
[image: Fourth Image]

Comment: Hey thanks for trying, although I am getting all the rows and all the columns of both the files placed side by side in both modified files. The duplicates as well as nonduplicates are showing.

Comment: Hey @sandy , I have modified the answer..can you try that

Comment: Now it shows correct no. of columns in each file, but it still shows all the rows in each file, the deduplication didn't happen.

Comment: Ah...made some last round of update in the code...I guess this time it should work..You can check temp_df column which is combined data frame without any duplicates

Comment: Getting error for this line `final_df1 = pd.merge(df1, temp_df, how='inner', on=['col1','col2','col3'])`. The error is `TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'NoneType'> was passed`

Comment: @sandy ... I did create 2 csv files similar to your data and added some snapshot for reference.also check  i have added dayfirst argument while reading.... check this useful url https://towardsdatascience.com/4-tricks-you-should-know-to-parse-date-columns-with-pandas-read-csv-27355bb2ad0e